# Delphi form won't open

Tags: forms, delphi

Just open my IDE (Delphi XE5) to continue coding and I got an error (never experienced similar error !)  on creating one form, due to field not found on a Tdbedit. Checked the Table is OK and so the field. Having no access to the form I 
am almost stump as I cannot edit the form. Before destroying the unit to start from scratch, as the form re-design would take time, can someone give an hint at least how to preserve the form drawing ? Thanks

Comment: Is the table located in a different form or datamodule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find a yourFormName.dfm file in your project folder. This is simply a text file containing the attributes for all of the form controls. You may well be able to correct your form by editing in wordpad (or insert you favourite editor).

```
  object DBText1: TDBText
    Left = 40
    Top = 48
    Width = 65
    Height = 17
    DataField = 'quoteref'
    DataSource = DataModule1.DSQuoteDetail
  end
```

As you can see the datafield and datasource are both present.

Comment: thanks a lot. I found DFMEdit few moment after the post and I recovered the form. Exactly like your way ! Thanks